# Using C# reflection to call a constructor

Tags: c#, reflection, constructor

I have the following scenario:

```
class Addition{
 public Addition(int a){ a=5; }
 public static int add(int a,int b) {return a+b; }
}
```

I am calling add in another class by:

```
string s="add";
typeof(Addition).GetMethod(s).Invoke(null, new object[] {10,12}) //this returns 22
```

I need a way similar to the above reflection statement to create a new object of type Addition using `Addition(int a)`

So I have string `s= "Addition"`, I want to create a new object using reflection.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to use reflection ? Reflection comes with a performance penalty, creates maintenances issues on the long run...

Comment: @Patrick, there are many cases where the performance penalty can be ignored as long as the user goal is achieved.

Answer (score 202, accepted):

I don't think `GetMethod` will do it, no - but [`GetConstructor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getconstructor.aspx) will.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

class Addition
{
    public Addition(int a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Constructor called, a={0}", a);
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Type type = typeof(Addition);
        ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int) });
        object instance = ctor.Invoke(new object[] { 10 });
    }
}
```

Yes, `Activator.CreateInstance` will work too. Use `GetConstructor` if you want to have more control over things, find out the parameter names etc. `Activator.CreateInstance` is great if you *just* want to call the constructor though.

Comment: Yes, but then you have to implement all the overload resolution rules to pick the right constructor.  Whereas the runtime will do it for you if you call http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx

Comment: So `GetConstructor` is preferred if you want to cache a delegate (performance enhancement when calling the same constructor many times), but for one-off use `Activator` would be easier.

Comment: @Ben: It definitely depends on your requirements, yes.

Comment: Jon Skeet - I want to try this snippet in Vb.NET, but there is a compiler Error in Vb.Net. Error in  New[] Error 8 Identifier expected.

Comment: @AkshayJoy: Well yes, arrays are initialized using different syntax in VB. Try compiling it in C# and then decompiling it in VB using something like Reflector - or use a C# to VB conversion tool.

Comment: @AkshayJoy: "its ot working" isn't nearly enough information. I've told you how to go about converting it mechanically - another alternative would be to make sure you understand the C# code and then make sure you know the VB syntax for constructing an array. Without wishing to be mean, if that's too much of a challenge then you should really *really* stay away from reflection.

Comment: Got it Thanks Jon Skeet  Dim params(0) As Type
                params(0) = GetType(FViewer)

                Dim constructorInfoObj As ConstructorInfo = objType.GetConstructor(params)

Comment: How do I call the constructor of the base class in case the class Addition doesn't have a constructor? @Jon Skeet

Comment: @SarathAvanavu: You wouldn't do that with reflection anyway... it's not clear what situation you're talking about, so it may be worth asking a new question (after searching for similar ones, of course).

Comment: It is also worth pointing out that there is another Invoke overload that allows you to invoke the constructor on a pre-existing instance. I think of the Invoke(Object[] args) as an allocator+initializer and Invoke(Object instance, Object[] args) as just an initializer.

Comment: Is there anyway to make this line dynamic ` Type type = typeof(Addition);` -  I mean I want to put that in a loop

Comment: @Chandra: Well without knowing any more context, it's hard to help. You could easily create an array or a list and loop over it...

Comment: @JonSkeet I solved it after replacing  ` Type type = typeof(Addition);` with `  Type type = Type.GetType("ClassName");`

Comment: With Activator, you cannot call private constructors, like a singleton class

Answer (score 56):

Yes, you can use [`Activator.CreateInstance`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx)

Comment: This really needs to be a proper answer

Comment: Interestingly, it seems that when constructors have parameters, then reflection is faster than Activator.CreateInstance: https://gist.github.com/KallDrexx/d08a60f2d807673af1d9e90e07d61aeb

Comment: @KallDrexx: Your benchmark is not measuring the cost of reflection correctly, because most of it is being done outside the measured function.  Move the `typeof(Program).GetConstructor(new[] {typeof(int)});` inside the function that calls it to have a fairer comparison.  And even then, you have chosen the exact matching overload ahead of time, while `Activator` has to do overload resolution across all constructors with the same number of parameters.

Comment: @BenVoigt while true, if you refresh you will see a new test where I did add this test case.  Even with considering the timing of `GetConstructor()` call it still is 2/3rds the time of an ACtivator.CreateInstance.  I also don't think it's unreasonable for Activator.CreateInstance to cache any reflection calls it may incur (since it's reasonable it may be called again) but whatever its cost is it apparently doesn't.