# Create a new object given the Type as a string?

Tags: c#, reflection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [using c# reflection to call a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255697/using-c-sharp-reflection-to-call-a-constructor)

How to call the constructor of a class from a string variable?

In PHP I can do this:

```
$myclassName = '\Namespace\MyClass';
$myParameters = array ('param1', 'param2');

$reflection = new \ReflectionClass($myclassName ); 
$myClassInstance = $reflection->newInstanceArgs($myParameters);
```

As I can do in C #?

i have a list o views like

- PersonView
- HouseView
- CarView

and her ViewModel

- PersonViewModel
- HouseViewModel
- CarViewModel

I have one ObservableCollection in my code i dont wana add a new Command for each kind

```
AddPersonView = new RelayCommand(() =>
{
  //code
});

AddCarView = new RelayCommand(() =>
{
  //code
});

//etc
```

i wanna pass CommandParameter to the same Command

```
AddView = new RelayCommand((name) =>
{
  // pseudo code
  var o = CreateIntance(name + "View");
  o.DataContext = CreateIntance(name + "ViewModel");
  _observableList.Add(o);
  // end 

});
```

Comment: the response in that question (http://stackoverflow.com/q/3255697/816721) is not clear for me

Comment: Why do you want to do this? In general, anything you have done in PHP is something you don't want to do in C#.

Comment: I wrote the name of my classes and their methods so that I can leave my code more maintainable

Comment: The keyword is "reflection". I have added the tag. Look at the related questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx).

Like

```
Namespace.MyClass obj = (Namespace.MyClass)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Namespace.MyClass), new[] { param1, param2});
```

Comment: ill try with `var o = System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("FullNameSpaceClassName"));`