# MSBuild: Describe Which Constructor to Call

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, msbuild-task

I'm working with an MSBuild task that needs to instantiate a class. The class originally had only one parameterless constructor, so all the MSBuild task needed was the type name to instantiate the class. Now we have a use case for the task to be run for specific constructors, and I don't know how to handle this in a generic way. Say I need to instantiate different flavors of `ClassA`:

```
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA() { }
    public ClassA(int someArgument) { }
    public ClassA(int someArgument, bool someOtherArgument) { }
}
```

This is what the original task looked like:

```
<DoSomethingTask Assembly="ContainsClassA.dll" Type="ClassA" />
```

My ideal task would look something like this so I could call any constructor that has primitive types as arguments:

```
<DoSomethingTask Assembly="ContainsClassA.dll" Type="ClassA">
    <ConstructorArgs>
        <Arg type="int">1</Arg>
        <Arg type="bool">True</Arg>
    </ConstructorArgs>
</DoSomethingTask>
```

I'm very lost on what to search for to get this type of functionality. I could do something like make a string property called `ConstructorArgs` and parse it using whatever format I want, but I'm hoping something cleaner exists. Thanks for any help you can provide!

Edit - In case anyone is wondering, the *actual* task I'm trying to modify creates a pregenerated view based on an instantiated Entity Framework DbContext. We have our own DbContext subclass with various constructors, and we'd like to be able to call a specific one during the view generation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to [use reflection and get a constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255697/using-c-sharp-reflection-to-call-a-constructor) for your DBContext subclass.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Build.Framework;
using Microsoft.Build.Utilities;

namespace TaskClass
{
    // Class to be created
    public class MyDbContext
    {
        public int ConstructorArg1 { get; set; }
        public string ConstructorArg2 { get; set; }

        public MyDbContext() { }

        public MyDbContext(int constructorArg1)
        {
            ConstructorArg1 = constructorArg1;
        }

        public MyDbContext(int constructorArg1, string constructorArg2)
        {
            ConstructorArg1 = constructorArg1;
            ConstructorArg2 = constructorArg2;
        }       
    }

    // MSBuild custom task
    public class DoSomethingTask : Task
    {
        public override bool Execute()
        {
            var taskParameters = new TaskParametersInfo();
            taskParameters.ExtractTaskParametersInfo(this);

            var type = typeof(MyDbContext);
            ConstructorInfo ctor = type.GetConstructor(taskParameters.Types.ToArray());

            if (ctor == null)
            {
                // If the constructor is not found, throw an error
                Log.LogError("There are no constructors defined with these parameters.");
                return false;
            }

            // Create your instance
            var myDbContext = (MyDbContext)ctor.Invoke(taskParameters.Values.ToArray());

            return true;
        }

        public int ConstructorArg1
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public string ConstructorArg2
        {
            get; 
            set;
        }

        public string ConstructorArg3
        { 
            get; 
            set; 
        }

        // Class to handle the task's parameters
        internal class TaskParametersInfo
        {
            public List<Type> Types { get; set; }
            public List<object> Values { get; set; }

            public TaskParametersInfo()
            {
                Types = new List<Type>();
                Values = new List<object>();
            }

            public void ExtractTaskParametersInfo(Task task)
            {
                foreach (var property in task.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Instance))
                {
                    var propertyValue = property.GetValue(task, null);
                    if (propertyValue != null)
                    {
                        Types.Add(property.PropertyType);
                        Values.Add(propertyValue);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Import the task on your msbuild project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" defaultTarget="DoSomething" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<UsingTask TaskName="TaskClass.DoSomethingTask" 
        AssemblyFile="TaskClass\TaskClass\bin\Debug\TaskClass.dll"/>
  <Target Name="DoSomething">
    <DoSomethingTask ConstructorArg1="123" ConstructorArg2="Are u talking to me?" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's similar to what I would actually do in the task, but the issue I'm trying to resolve involves an unknown number of arguments of various types. So i might have constructors like: (string, int, int), (string, bool), (string, bool, bool). I was more looking for how to provide an array in MSBuild of strings that had a primitive type descriptor.