# Reflection for Constructors

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Here:

`defaultCon` binds itself to `Dog()` Constructor

`legCon` binds itself to `Dog(int legs)` Constructor

Why do we specify

`new Type[0]` in Line X even though there are no parameters in Default Constructor

`(new[] { typeof(int) })` in Line Y ! Curly braces inside argument/parameter field.Similar problem in Line Z.

I searched on StackOverflow - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255697/using-c-sharp-reflection-to-call-a-constructor) answer came close but doesn't answer my question. Here is my code:

```
namespace Coding
{
    internal class Dog
    {
        public int NumberOfLegs { get; set; }
        public Dog()
        {
            NumberOfLegs = 4;
        }

        public Dog(int legs)
        {
            NumberOfLegs = legs;
        }
    }

    public class Class1
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*line X*/  var defaultCon = typeof(Dog).GetConstructor(new Type[0]); // Get Default Constructor without any params
            /*line Y*/  var legCon = typeof(Dog).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int) });//get constructor with param int

            var defaultDog = defaultCon.Invoke(null) as Dog;//invoke defaultCon for a Dog Object
            /*Line Z*/  var legDog = legCon.Invoke(new object[] { 5 });//invoke legCon for a Dog object(Sets number of legs as 5) as Dog

            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've answered, but it's not clear whether the problem is actually your understanding of reflection, or that you simply don't know what an expression such as `new[] { typeof(int) }` means - and that in itself doesn't have anything to do with reflection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why do we specify "new Type[0]" in Line X even though there are no parameters in Default Constructor

To say that there are no parameters - so the array of parameter *types* is empty.

> Why do we specify "(new[] { typeof(int) })" in Line Y! Curly braces inside argument/parameter field.

To create an array or parameter types with a single element - the type corresponding to `int`.

> Similar problem in Line Z.

Same answer, except this time you're creating an array of arguments, instead of parameter types.

Comment: So your answer means  in Line X "new Type[0]" effectively null ! Is there any other equivalent code we could have used as parameter in Line Y !

Comment: @RahulJha: No, a reference to an empty array is very different (in general) to a null reference.

Answer (score 0):

The [simplest overload of `Type.GetConstructor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h93ya84h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) still takes an array of types to indicate the parameters of the constructor you're trying to get.

The value `Type[0]` is an *empty array*, which indicates no parameters.