# How do I get the generic, T, of a List<T> field and use it as a generic of another constructor?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, generics, reflection, constructor

I am writing a `JsonMapper` in order to map a JSON String to the fields of a C# class using [SimpleJSON](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON), similar to `JSONUtility` so that I can have greater control over the mapping. I'm not inclined to write the code for mapping each class as I will have many multiple classes with varying fields.

```
public class JsonMapper<T>
{
    public string jsonString;
    public T mappedObj;

    public JsonMapper(string json)
    {
        jsonString = json;
        JSONNode jn = JSON.Parse(json);

        Type t = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType(typeof(T).FullName);
        mappedObj = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(t);

        foreach (FieldInfo field in typeof(T).GetFields())
        {
            switch (field.FieldType.Name)
            {
                case "Int32":
                    field.SetValue(mappedObj, int.Parse(jn[field.Name]));
                    Debug.Log(field + ": " + field.GetValue(mappedObj));
                    break;
                    ...
```

I've used reflection in order to map primitive data types so far, but currently I am stuck trying to map lists. I'm trying to obtain the generic, `T`, of the `List`, and recursively create another instance of my `JsonMapper`. Below is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
case "List`1":
    Type genericType = field.FieldType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    foreach (var genericJson in jn[field.Name])
    {
        //This line does not work, it is pseudocode
        JsonMapper<genericType> recurJM = new JsonMapper<genericType>(genericJson.ToString());
    }
    break;
```

To do so I have referenced [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method) to invoke generic methods using reflection and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255697/using-c-sharp-reflection-to-call-a-constructor) to invoke constructors. However, I can't seem to find a way to invoke a constructor with generics.

My question is: How do I achieve this particular line of code in the above code snippet?

```
JsonMapper<genericType> recurJM = new JsonMapper<genericType>(genericJson.ToString());
```

Comment: Have you looked at `Type.MakeGenericType` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype)?

Comment: Any reason for the `unity3d` tag?

Comment: Thank you Rand Random, the linked question seems to solve my problem, I’ll try it out. The Unity3D tag is because I’m building in Unity3D and I’m trying to achieve a similar result to Unity3D’s JSONUtility.