# How do you pass and use a generic Type with a method?

Tags: c#, list, generics, types, instance

In terms of the DRY principle, I'm seeking to reduce the methods below (there are other lists that need generating, so number is larger in real life):

```cs
public static List<Genre> GetGenres(ApiCredentials apiCredentials = null, ApiServerParameters apiServerParameters = null)
{
    List<Genre> returns = new List<Genre>();

    GetData getData = new GetData(apiCredentials, apiServerParameters);
    var outcome = getData.GetListOrInfo(Enums.ApiQueryType.GenreList);

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(outcome.Data.ToString());
    
    foreach (var genre in xdoc.Descendants("genre"))
    {
        returns.Add(new Genre(genre));
    }       

    return returns;
}

public static List<Language> GetLanguages(ApiCredentials apiCredentials = null, ApiServerParameters apiServerParameters = null)
{
    List<Language> returns = new List<Language>();

    GetData getData = new GetData(apiCredentials, apiServerParameters);
    var outcome = getData.GetListOrInfo(Enums.ApiQueryType.LanguageList);

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(outcome.Data.ToString());

    foreach (var language in xdoc.Descendants("langue"))
    {
        returns.Add(new Language(language));
    }

    return returns;
}
```

I've figured out how to pass a generic `T`, but cannot figure how to raise a new instance of Type `T`:

```cs
public static List<T> GetList<T>(Enums.ApiQueryType queryType, string xElementName,
    ApiCredentials apiCredentials = null, ApiServerParameters apiServerParameters = null)
{

    List<T> returns = new List<T>();

    GetData getData = new GetData(apiCredentials, apiServerParameters);
    var outcome = getData.GetListOrInfo(queryType);

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(outcome.Data.ToString());

    foreach (var element in xdoc.Descendants(xElementName))
    {
        returns.Add(new T(element)); /// Doesn't compile
    }

    return null;
}
```

How do I do this?

==========================================

ANSWER:
Thanks to all the helpful replies - this put me on the right track. The best approach I found for me (in terms of readability and simplicity):

```cs
public static List<T> GetList<T>(Enums.ApiQueryType queryType, string xElementName,
    ApiCredentials apiCredentials = null, ApiServerParameters apiServerParameters = null)
{

    List<T> returns = new List<T>();

    GetData getData = new GetData(apiCredentials, apiServerParameters);
    var outcome = getData.GetListOrInfo(queryType);

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(outcome.Data.ToString());

    foreach (var element in xdoc.Descendants(xElementName))
    {
        var obj = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), element);
        returns.Add(obj);
    }

    return returns;
}
```

Comment: What C# / .NET version are you using?  Possibly [Is there a generic constructor with parameter constraint in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1852837/3744182) may be relevant.

Comment: Also (and this might be a typo in the question), `xdoc.Descendants("genre")` should probably be `xdoc.Descendants(xElementName)`.

Comment: Rather than copying an answer into your question, you should [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) one of the answers added to your question, or add one yourself.

Comment: Reflection is the simpler solution, but it comes at the price of having potential exceptions blowing up only on runtime, where as a factory-based solution would have thrown compile time exceptions. Personally, if this was production grade code - I would go further and try to tie the element name and the factory function together with the ApiQueryType  value that matches them.

Comment: FYI you don't have to copy in the answer, just the check mark ("accepted answer") on that answer is enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either add a constraint on T's constructor, however, unless this has recently changed, this won't work for a constructor with parameters.
I.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-constraint

or

use **reflection** to retrieve a constructor for T that has one parameter of the type you want to pass.
E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3255716/38368

Comment: Reflection proved to be the best route for me - thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since the constructor takes a parameter, you can't simply use the `new` generic constraint, but nothing is stopping you from passing a factory method to your method - one that will take in an `XElement` and return `T`:

```
public static List<T> GetList<T>(Enums.ApiQueryType queryType, string xElementName, Func<XElement, T> factory,
    ApiCredentials apiCredentials = null, ApiServerParameters apiServerParameters = null)
{
    List<T> returns = new List<T>();

    GetData getData = new GetData(apiCredentials, apiServerParameters);
    var outcome = getData.GetListOrInfo(queryType);

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(outcome.Data.ToString());

    foreach (var element in xdoc.Descendants(xElementName))
    {
        returns.Add(factory(element)); 
    }

    return returns;
}
```

usage:

```
// Enums.ApiQueryType.Genere assumed
var geners = GetList<Genre>(Enums.ApiQueryType.Genere, e => new Genere(e));
```